# Swift - Table View not populating with data but shows no errors

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Using the following tutorial I have attempted to display some stock information that would populate in a table. I have created both the table view controller as well as the table view cell and linked stockTableViewCell with the table view cell. However I am unable to link the tableview on the Main storyboard with the custom table view controller.

Basically every time I try to enter it into the custom class field it does not apply and when I navigate away it disappears

My question is, is there something wrong with my view controller or table view cell or is there something in my storyboard that I have misconfigured?

Tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html

## Table View Controller

```
import UIKit

class stocksTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    // Mark: Properties

    var stocks = [stockData]()
    let stock = stockinfo()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadSampleStockData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadSampleStockData () {

        var stock1: stockData = stockData(name: "", askPrice: "", percentageChange: "", stockTicker: "")
        var stock2: stockData = stockData(name: "", askPrice: "", percentageChange: "", stockTicker: "")
        var stock3: stockData = stockData(name: "", askPrice: "", percentageChange: "", stockTicker: "")

        stock.getInfo("FB") {(name, price, change) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            stock1 = stockData(name: name, askPrice: price, percentageChange: change, stockTicker: "FB")})
        }

        stock.getInfo("MSFT") {(name, price, change) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            stock2 = stockData(name: name, askPrice: price, percentageChange: change, stockTicker: "MSFT")})
        }

        stock.getInfo("APPL") {(name, price, change) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            stock3 = stockData(name: name, askPrice: price, percentageChange: change, stockTicker: "APPL")})
        }

        stocks += [stock1, stock2, stock3]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stocks.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "stockViewCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! stockTableViewCell

        let stock = stocks[indexPath.row]

        cell.stockName.text = stock.name
        cell.stockPercentage.text = stock.percentageChange
        cell.stockDollarChange.text = stock.askPrice
        cell.stockTicker.text = stock.stockTicker

        return cell
    }
}
```

## Table View Cell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class stockTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var stockTicker: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stockPercentage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stockName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stockDollarChange: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization Code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: Are you referring to the loadSampleStockData(), I called that in the viewDidLoad() function, or is that not what you are asking?

Comment: I'm referring to the code above.

Comment: In that case, I don't believe I do! Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what issues you are having without looking at your project but what are you trying to enter into the custom class? You should enter stocksTableViewController and it should work, unless you didn't drag in a TableViewController on your storyboard. And you don't need to register your cell in the viewDidLoad ignore that comment.

Here use this updated code, your are trying to set up two types of view controllers to one view on your storyboard put this code into your class dashboardViewController and this should get you on the right track, don't forget to connect the outlet for the tableView property on this code when you implement it.

```
class dashboardViewController: DefaultViewController,     UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var balanceLabel: UILabel!

  var stocks = [stockData]()
  let stock = stockinfo()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    loadSampleStockData()
    user.newUser() // Move to login function when login and registration is implemented

//Sets the Balance Label on Dashboard
balanceLabel.text = "$" + String(format: "%.2f", user.getBalance())
  }

 func loadSampleStockData () {

var stock1: stockData = stockData(name: "", askPrice: "", percentageChange: "", stockTicker: "")
var stock2: stockData = stockData(name: "", askPrice: "", percentageChange: "", stockTicker: "")
var stock3: stockData = stockData(name: "", askPrice: "", percentageChange: "", stockTicker: "")

stock.getInfo("FB") {(name, price, change) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  stock1 = stockData(name: name, askPrice: price, percentageChange: change, stockTicker: "FB")})
    }

stock.getInfo("MSFT") {(name, price, change) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  stock2 = stockData(name: name, askPrice: price, percentageChange: change, stockTicker: "MSFT")})
}

stock.getInfo("APPL") {(name, price, change) in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  stock3 = stockData(name: name, askPrice: price, percentageChange: change, stockTicker: "APPL")})
}

stocks += [stock1, stock2, stock3]
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return stocks.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cellIdentifier = "stockViewCell"

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! stockTableViewCell

let stock = stocks[indexPath.row]

cell.stockName.text = stock.name
cell.stockPercentage.text = stock.percentageChange
cell.stockDollarChange.text = stock.askPrice
cell.stockTicker.text = stock.stockTicker

return cell
    }`
  }
```

Comment: Which TableView are you trying to populate? The one on the Dashboard? Portfolio? AddStock or Leaderboard? Also all of these views are ViewControllers so your UITableViewController would not fit in the custom class section.

Comment: I'm trying to populate it into the Dashboard. Oh I see that makes sense. How would I go about fixing it? Thanks so much zsteed, I'm new to iOS development so I'm still learning the basics. Ps. The way I'm using views and view controllers is that correct?

Comment: Awesome that seemed to work. But now I'm getting this error: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1a1934bc0) to 'NSString' (0x1a193f7e8). Any thoughts? Again @zsteed I can't thank you enough for your help.

Comment: With out jumping into your networking to much, just change your code to this and it will be a quick fix for now, but probably won't solve the problem long term                     let companyName: String = quote["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let askPrice: String = quote["Ask"] as? String ?? ""
                    let percentageChange: String = quote["ChangeinPercent"] as? String ?? "", good luck

Comment: And If these solved your problems mark my answer with a check.

Comment: Thanks so much that definitely fixed my problems and went above and beyond, I'm still having a problem with the text in the cells displaying as I think it's possible that somehow the changes above seem to have now caused the completion statement to pass a blank string? Any thought. Again thank you so much you are going beyond and above, helping me out on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to register your customtableviewcell in **viewDidLoad()**

Further you can also check the following link

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/06/ios-custom-uitableviewcell-example.html

Comment: Thanks! As I'm fairly new to development, I read over the link you provided however I'm still a bit lost to how I would go about registering my customtableviewcell in the viewDidLoad() of my view controller.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I tried using this: tableView.registerClass(stockTableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "stockViewCell") to register the class but I'm still trying to figure out exactly how to use this call as right now I'm getting an error.

Comment: Please check the sample code that the link shows @MarkGong-Guy

Comment: If everything is designed in Interface Builder – like suggested in the Apple tutorial – you don't need to register anything.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your project and I've some points that can help you:

1. You don't have the outlet for your search field. You inserted the UISearchDisplayController but not connected with your class AddStockViewController.
2. and most important [UISearchDisplayerController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchdisplaycontroller) is deprecated try to use the UISearchController or UISearchBar.

o/

Comment: Awesome thanks so much I'll definitely make those changes. I appreciate you looking at my project and giving me feedback!